# Custom Range Slider

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am trying to do a custom range slider in Angular Material. But I don't know how to change the default size and color. Can any one help me with that.

**HTML**

`<mat-slider thumbLabel max="30" value="10"></mat-slider>`

What I am Getting

[image: What I Have]

What I Need

[image: What I What]

Comment: You might have to study the original implementation of the [SLIDER](https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/lib/slider) and find the spots you need to change.

Comment: Might be simpler: google: "stackblitz angular slider", find something that is lightweight and already does alot you need, tweak it. It surely helps if you level up your css skills.

Comment: I changed color but I couldn't change the width of slider

Comment: Please show what you have tried in a stackblitz. With ng5-slider it could look something like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lerpgo

Answer (score 1):

**Please update this style in your css**

```
    .mat-accent .mat-slider-thumb, .mat-accent .mat-slider-thumb-label, .mat-accent .mat-slider-track-fill {
    background-color: #fd7175;
    z-index: 1;
}

.mat-slider-horizontal .mat-slider-ticks-container {
    background-color: #986ed8;
}

.mat-slider-thumb {
    position: absolute;
    right: -5px;
    bottom: -10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 7px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 0;
    transform: scale(.7);
    transition: transform .4s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1), background-color .4s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1), border-color .4s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
}

.mat-accent .mat-slider-thumb-label-text {
    color: #ab42ab;
}

.mat-slider:not(.mat-slider-disabled).cdk-focused .mat-slider-thumb-label {
    border-radius: 50% 50% 0;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```